# Is there a way to get the detailed battery usage for my app on Android 5.0/5.1/6.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, battery, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

In Android 6.0, we can the detailed battery usage for each app as shown below. Is there a way to get these numbers programmatically within this app? I tried to use command "dumpsys batterystats --charged MY_APP" and parse the returned values, but this command can only be run by system app or from adb. Is there way to get similar data from my own app programmatically?

[image: Detailed battery usage]

Comment: You've seen: http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/batterystats-battery-historian/index.html and https://github.com/google/battery-historian

Comment: did you found any answer